# Error Accessing GoogleCredentials

Tags: android, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have the following code to access the Calendar API using OAUTH 2.0.

```
public static Calendar build(String accessToken) {
    HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
    JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
    httpRequestInitializer(credential);
    Log.i("Reached calendar builder", "Reached calendar builder");

    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential();


    Calendar service = new Calendar.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, credential)
            .setApplicationName("Meetrbus/1.0")
            .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential);
            .setJsonHttpRequestInitializer(
                    new JsonHttpRequestInitializer() {

                        public void initialize(JsonHttpRequest request) {
                            CalendarRequest calendarRequest = (CalendarRequest) request;

                            // TODO: Get an API key from Google's APIs
                            // Console:
                            // https://code.google.com/apis/console.
                            calendarRequest
                                    .setKey("API_ACCESS_KEY");
                        }
                    }).build();




    return service;
}
```

When i run the code,the app force closes and logcat gives me the following error:

`Could not find class 'com.google.api.client.util.Clock', referenced from method                        com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.<init>`

I have tried changing close to everything and now i have no cluee as to what to do!

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the google-http-java-client jars in your class path.

The latest google-http-java-client can be obtained from here:
http://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/downloads/list

Comment: I had done that already tried redoing it but didn't fix it. Then i rolled back to using the previous version of the api and it doesn't throw any errors. Still no idea what ticked it off

Comment: The google docs and google samples don't match any longer. They are out of sync completely. Since one week I try to get a working example with the current APIs.